# GNOME - How to remove app launchers from the activities menu

Tags: gnome

I want to know if there is a way to remove application launchers in GNOME's activities menu:

[image]

I also want to know If I can make folders (or groups) like the existing `utilities` folder in the picture:

[image]

After I install applications they always install other dependencies which I don't want to browse through every time I am searching for an application.

In Openbox this was exeptionally well done using `~/.config/openbox/menu.xml` where I specified exact file / folder structure which benefited my productivity.

Comment: Please post the second part (i.e. folders in Activities) as a separate question if possible because it sounds like a separate issue. Ping me if you do so.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

App launchers shown in GNOME Activities are located either in `/usr/share/applications/` or `~/.local/share/applications/` as `.desktop` files.

You can hide an individual app launcher from Activities by adding an extra `NoDisplay=true` line to the corresponding `.desktop` file.

It is generally not advisable to edit the `.desktop` file located in `/usr/share/applications/`. Instead copy the file to `~/.local/share/applications/` first and make the change to the copied file.

---

If you can't find the right `.desktop` file in any of the two locations mentioned above, try `/usr/local/share/applications` too.

Comment: Is it possible to screw anything if I just delete everything from there and manually ad them myself? Also is it possible that they get overwritten on system upgrades?

Comment: Theoretically it shouldn't cause any issue with the app itself. But as you have suspected, an application update will create/overwrite the `.desktop` file(s).

Comment: Probably .desktop files in `.local/share/applications` won't get overwritten on upgrade while the ones in `/usr/share/applications` will.

Comment: @71GA Yes, that's why it's advisable to create a local copy first and make the changes there.

Comment: A minimalist solution would be creating a same-name .desktop file at ~/local/share/applications/ with only the "NoDisplay=true" line. I create this file and create several symlinks to mask the apps that I don't use.

Comment: @WuXingbo Can you describe your way a bit more? I love openbox where I can define what is in the menu...

Answer (score 4):

In my case, the application's identity was in `~/.local/share/applications` but it was obfuscated through a name like

```
chrome-hmbjbjdpkobdjplfobhljndfdfdipjhg-Default.desktop
```

making it difficult to find by name (in my case, the icon was named "Zoom"). For me, the solution was to run

```
cd ~/.local/share/applications
grep -rn Zoom
```

with "Zoom" replaced with the icon name. Once you have found the file, you can view its contents to uninstall the program it is linked to as well.

Comment: It is a mistery to me why they need to overcomplicate things at GNOME.

Answer (score 2):

The GUI way could be to install "Alacarte". It's super easy to manage and remove app launchers from the menu.

Comment: Does "Alacarte" keep launchers removed even after updates?

Comment: If the application doesn't automatically create a .desktop file or launcher for itself then yes, it will still be removed after updates. BUT almost every applications creates a .desktop/launcher file upon install my guess is that the launcher will come up. I haven't tried it yet.

Answer (score 2):

The package `menulibre` provides the possibility to hide launchers with a simple switch:

(It's in french here, you'll find this option in your language)

[image]

**Don't forget** to save your modifications with the following top-left icon:

[image]

Comment: Beware: this method also removes applications from showing up in gnome's type-to-search list of applications!

Answer (score 0):

This was too easy and yet I didn’t know either and had to search far and wide. You can easily make new ‘app icon folder groups’ by dragging an icon over a second icon. When you see it highlight release it and now both icons will be in the group that you can click on and name. Keep adding icons in the same manner. It works the same on an iPad. It never occurred to me it would be so simple! Removing icons seems to be much harder, and I can’t figure out why PopShop is suddenly creating extras.